# Display an array value as default content

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, tinymce

Setting TinyMce into an application I would it can display the object array

```
<?php echo $data[13];?>
```

In the init file I tried in with console.log but it doesn't work

```
tinymce.init({
    selector:"textarea.shortdesc",    
    init_instance_callback: "insert_contents"

});

function insert_contents(inst){
        console.log(data[13]);
    }
```

Did you know different way to echo array value into js?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. It's enough to implement you text-area field such as

```
<textarea class="longdesc" rows="12" ><?php echo $prod_info[13];?></textarea>
```